# Azure IoT Hub: Docker Module on IoT Edge device does not update?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I am using Azure IoT Hub with an Edge device and have installed the Edge runtime on the device.
I used [this](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/364#issuecomment-424947107) tutorial from Microsoft to get started.

Now I want to customize this Java code. I then again build, push and deploy the container according to the tutorial, but the changes are not show when I run the command `iotedge logs MyModule -f` op the edge device.

I already found this: https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/364#issuecomment-424947107
But it does not seem to help for me.

Can someone help me?

Comment: The link you provided for the tutorial now points to the github issue, could you update it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the latest in the tag to identify the updated version. It would be better if you could change the version number as well. Finally, check  if the  build you created is also reflecting the changes you have made before pushing it  to the container.